# Find how many columns and rows along a circle is

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the following code will make an array of circles. I want to be able to click on a circle and have a popup tell me how many rows and columns along that circle is starting from (1,1).

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var gCanvasElement = ctx;

ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";

ctx.strokeRect(20,20,800,600);

// Positions are hardcoded to make sure that circle starts from the right place
var startX = 55;
var startY = 55;

console.clear();

for(var i=1;i<=8;i++){
    console.group(i);
    for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle='green';
        //radius is hardcoded to 30 for testing purpose
        ctx.arc(startX*j + (j-1)*10,startY*i + (i-1)*10,30,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

        //console log
        console.group(j);    
        console.log(startX*j + (j-1)*10);
        console.log(startY*i + (i-1)*10);
        console.groupEnd(j);
    }

    console.groupEnd(i);
}
```

Comment: so it's like a grid, what you want to know which entry that circle is?

Comment: Yes like a grid, I want to know 1) how far down the circle is and 2) how far across the circle is.
So like the first circle (top left) is 1,1. The next one is 1,2 and the one below that is 2,2

Comment: using jquery $.data() you can store the x and y value of each circle, then access them on click.

Comment: Could you show me how to add that in? I've never used it before

Comment: Consider canvas to be an image. It doesn't actually store shapes (unlike SVG does). What you can do is bind on click event, take its coordinates (pageX, pageY), and do some math to calculate which circle was under the cursor.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of a tutorial or any information on binding anywhere would you? :( @Yury Tarabanko

Comment: @user3733042 You need to use `addEventListener` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener 
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/Jct6j/ you need to do some math to find out which circle current coordinates belong to if any.

Answer (score 0):

As I've written in my comment canvas is just a raster image. It does not store shapes unlike vector graphics (SVG). So you need to use math to find if the user clicked the circle or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/Jct6j/

```
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) { //helper to get distance between 2 points
    return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1));    
}

function center(i) { //helper to get coordinates of i-th circle
    return (i*2-1)*radius + (i-1)*step/2;    
}

c.addEventListener('click', function(ev){ //click lister
    var x = ev.pageX - c.offsetLeft - (startX - radius), //normalized coords
        y = ev.pageY - c.offsetTop - (startY - radius), //normalized coords
        grid = 2*radius + step/2,
        i, j, d;

    if(x < 0 || y < 0) { return;} //out of circles

    //cell inside your grid
    i = Math.ceil(x/grid); 
    j = Math.ceil(y/grid);

    if(i > j) { return;} //out of circles

    d = distance(x, y, center(i), center(j));

    if(d > radius) {return;} //to far from center


    console.log(i, j);
}, false);
```